# Clicking anywhere in JavaFX Listview returns index -1 and crashes

Tags: java, javafx

Im working on a simple todo list. Everything was working until fine until now. I worked on a couple methods that save data (no UI work at all) and when I came to test it all, I noticed that my list view has a blue outline around it and tapping things breaks the program. 
There are two scenarios:

1) run program -> tapping anywhere in list view (outside of the todo 1 cell) crashes program

2) run program -> tap todo cell -> todo info screen opens -> close info screen -> tapping anywhere in list view opens that todo info screen.

Heres an image of what that looks like

[image]

There error I get is: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out-of-bounds for length 1

```
 static void selectedIndexListener(ListView<Todo> listView) {
    listView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            int selectedTodoIndex = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            StageController.launchSelectedTodoStage(TodoList.getTodoListInstance().getTodoAtIndex(selectedTodoIndex));
        }
    });
}
```

and then

```
 static Todo getTodoAtIndex(int index) {
    return todoList.get(index);
}
```

I have an ObservableList that holds all the todos and so hence the error.

Im pretty comfortable with java but I'm new to javafx. The reason i'm building this program is to practice java, not so much javafx. That being said, i have no idea where to start debugging this. 
All I can say is that the last things I did was write functions to save and load data using JSON. The biggest change is the fact that the list view get populated upon running the program where as before i used to run it, then add data. However scenario number 1 (crashing) happens when I comment out the load and save methods (i.e. run the program with no initial data as I used to). At the moment I am more concerned about the first scenario than the second

I barely ever post on here so let me know if there is anything I should include to help you help me.

Comment: Please include the code that is generating the exception

Comment: @James_D Hey, I added my code that shows up in the stack trace

Comment: Off-topic: why is everything `static`? This is a horrendous code smell.

Comment: @James_D I'm still a college student dude. I can't see far enough into the future when I write new things so i just dump code into the compiler to get things working then I clean it all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing is selected, then

```
listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()
```

will return `-1` (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedIndexProperty)). So in the case where nothing is selected, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. On the other hand, if you select something, then click in an empty cell, the selection is not changed and so you get the details of the previously-selected item.

It's generally a bad idea to equate mouse clicks with selection. While they're obviously related, as you've discovered they are not the same thing.

If you want to handle mouse-clicks on a cell, instead of registering a mouse event handler with the `ListView` itself, use a cell factory to define a cell that has the appropriate mouse-handlers registered. So something like:

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    ListCell<Todo> cell = new ListCell<Todo>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Todo item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item == null ? "" : item.toString());
        }
    };
    cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
            StageController.launchSelectedTodoStage(cell.getItem());
        }
    });
    return cell ;
});
```

Comment: Oh awesome, that solved it. I guess I got really lucky and just didn't encounter that error until now which is why I thought everything was fine. Thanks man!